# Accordion: close all rows except the clicked one

Tags: javascript, accordion

I'm trying to close all rows of an accordion except the selected one, but I can't achieve it.

This is my code (it is based on this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_animate)

```
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      panel.style.marginTop = "0";
      panel.style.marginBottom = "0";
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      panel.style.marginTop = "32px";
      panel.style.marginBottom = "32px";
    } 
  });
}
```

Thank you very much for any help you can give.

Best,
Marco

Comment: there is no way this can work, you don't even have a script tag around your javascript. Is this by any chance just a sample of your actual code?

Comment: Yes indeed, this is just a sample